# Elastic Search different field

Tags: json, elasticsearch, postman, elasticsearch-5

I made a simple mapping with two fields where i am analyzing one field which is text type and other field is a keyword type. example

```
fields: Category_one, Category_two
Data
{"Category_one": "liked wine", "Category_two":"Wine"}
{"Category_one": "liked pasta", "Category_two":"pasta"}
{"Category_one": "liked wine and pasta", "Category_two":"Wine and pasta"}
{"Category_one": "liked wine so much", "Category_two":"Wine"} 

...........
..........
.....
```

Now I wrote a search query for the index.

```
Get _search/cat
    {
    "size": 20,
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "Category_one.ngrams": {
            "query": "Nice food place in XYZ location",
            "analyzer": "standard"
          }
        }
        }
      }
    }
```

It's working fine.  I want to find the top 5 unique `Category_two` values according to their match query score in `Category_one`.

For example :

Let's say the query returns 20 results("size" in the query above) with different scores, out of which first 6 are wine(`Category_two`), next 4 are pasta(`Category_two`), and so on..

These 20 results have duplicates. How can I fetch top 3 unique values from `Category_two` for "Wine", "pasta", "wine and pasta" as per their scores in the `Category_one` match score?

Can someone help me understand how to approach this problem? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please format your question and try to explain it better, I think community is having hard time to understand your question.

Comment: Could you tell me which part is unclear? so i can explain better

Comment: I edit it again, could you check it now?